# SQL count and sum some row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting a calculation error in my code

```
SELECT dep_id,
   dept_info.name AS dept_name,
   count(dep_id) AS totalInovators,
   count(user_id) AS totalIdea,
   sum(POINT) AS totalpoint
FROM user_info
JOIN dept_info ON user_info.dep_id =dept_info.id
JOIN user_idea ON user_info.id=user_idea.user_id
GROUP BY dep_id
ORDER BY dep_id DESC
```

**My output result:**

[image: My output result]

**Expected result:**

[image: Expected output]

**With my table user_info :**

[image: user_info]

**My user_idea :**

[image: user_idea]

**My dept_info :**

[image]

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: You are referencing a column called "point" but it looks like it should be "points".  Also using SUM on the id column doesn't seem logical... did you perhaps mean to use COUNT there?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not images.

Comment: I've completed a few tables but I don't know how to format a table in text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below the query that solve your problem:

```
select 
    user_info.dep_id, 
    dept_info.name,
    count(*) as totalInovators, 
    sum(ideas_count) as totalIdea,
    sum(point) as totalpoint
from
    -- first we aggregate table user_idea
    (select user_id, count(*) ideas_count from user_idea group by user_id) ideas
    -- and after join rest of required tables
    join user_info on ideas.user_id = user_info.id
    join dept_info on dept_info.id = user_info.dep_id
group by user_info.dep_id,  dept_info.name;
```

Working code here: [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e&sqlses=a5056a047d2d00a493ef8841227939b0)

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are joining along different dimensions.  If so, a quick-and-easy solution uses `count(distinct)`:

```
select d.id, d.name as dept_name, count(distinct u.id) as totalInovators,
       count(*) as totalIdea, sum(i.point) as totalpoint
from user_info u join
     dept_info d
     on u.dep_id = d.id join
     user_idea i
     on u.id = i.user_id
group by d.id 
order by d.id desc
```